# How to filter task_status as a seen, accepted, rejected?

Tags: objective-c, json

This is my json format:

```
{
  "my_todo": [
    {
      "task_id": "71",
      "task_status": "Seen",
      "task_status_id": "2",
      "task_status_color": "warning",
      "task_sub": "Test",
      "task_content": "Testing",
      "task_from_id": "2",
      "task_from": "Aditi Sen",
      "task_lastdate": "2016-01-21"
    },
    {
      "task_id": "70",
      "task_status": "Accepted",
      "task_status_id": "4",
      "task_status_color": "success",
      "task_sub": "checking ",
      "task_content": "no of new task",
      "task_from_id": "2",
      "task_from": "Aditi Sen",
      "task_lastdate": "2016-01-19"
    },
    {
      "task_id": "69",
      "task_status": "Accepted",
      "task_status_id": "4",
      "task_status_color": "success",
      "task_sub": "checking ",
      "task_content": "no of new task",
      "task_from_id": "2",
      "task_from": "Aditi Sen",
      "task_lastdate": "2016-01-19"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a decent explanation about the problem and show us what you tried please?

Comment: i just want data from this services status wise in different table view .task_status "seen" data in 1 view, task_status "accepted" all data in another view. please help me out this. advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/).

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"task_status contains[cd] %@", @"seen"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[jsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it has solved your issue?

Comment: @ios: as per the above reminder, please accept this answer if it helped you. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so that it turns green. This gives your helpful respondent some points, which in turn encourages them to help someone again.